# Warning pop up is shy and hide behind How to Ask big brother

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]

Firefox 34.0, Windows.

Comment: I read it, and I don't think that regex is going to work

Comment: Reproduced in `Chrome V.37.0` too.

Comment: COMIC SANS!  Slowly I turned... step by step... inch by inch...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has been fixed on live. Please let me know if it still happens for you.